# What is an orthogonal monometric system?

Tags: geometry

I am reading a journal paper. In that I have chosen a flat slab as a reference geometry for some object. Then they have placed a orthogonal monometric system x,y,z with the plan of xy coinciding with the symmetry of the slab.

Can somebody tell me the meaning of "orthogonal monometric system"? I tried to google this. But could not understand the meaning of this.

Comment: Monometric System: The two coordinate axes X - axis and Y - axis
has its own vector and if we assume that the two lines are each given the
same unit of measure then the coordinate system is called monometric.

Comment: Orthogonal Monometric System: A system of cartesian coordinates
such that the axes are pairwise orthogonal and the unit of measure on
each of the axis is the same is called an orthogonal monometric system.